# How to remove the escape characters \n and \n\n in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have the string

*\nTirage de l'édition : 300 ex.\n\n\"Il faut suivre avec le plus grand intérêt l'entreprise de Michèle Battut, où se reflètent, s'unissent et parfois se combattent, tous les courants qui, après la tyrannie de l'abstrait cherchent à rendre le monde à la peinture\".\n\nJean.*,

its have **\n** and **\n\n**.

remove the escape characters, using these codes,

```
NSCharacterSet* charsToTrim = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@" \n"];
NSString* trimmedStr = [aStr stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:charsToTrim];
```

but its not working, you have any suggestions, I have appreciate.

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: `stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet` trimming remove only at the beginning and at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got answer and its working for me,

```
    NSString *str =\nTirage de l'édition : 300 ex.\n\n\"Il faut suivre avec le plus grand intérêt l'entreprise de Michèle Battut, où se reflètent, s'unissent et parfois se combattent, tous les courants qui, après la tyrannie de l'abstrait cherchent à rendre le monde à la peinture\".\n\nJean.,;
    str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\n" withString:@""];
    str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\\"" withString:@"\""];

    tvConditions.text   =  str;
```

Answer (score 2):

As you see, your result String displaying '\n', it is clear it contains`\\n` not '\n',

```
    NSString * newString= [myString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\n" withString:@""];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just remove '\n' then try following code.

My tested code

```
NSString *str = @"\nTirage de l'édition : 300 ex.\n\n\"Il faut suivre avec le plus grand intérêt l'entreprise de Michèle Battut, où se reflètent, s'unissent et parfois se combattent, tous les courants qui, après la tyrannie de l'abstrait cherchent à rendre le monde à la peinture\".\n\nJean.,";
str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
NSLog(@"%@",str);
```

Comment: I tested it. It remove '\n' from string.

Comment: How you can store string into variable? can you show more code?

Comment: i have get the server response string, then change put the string its not working.

Comment: I add more content into answer.please check.

Comment: `NSString *str = po.sConditions;
    str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
    
    tvConditions.text   =  str;`

Comment: Is it a bad conversion, and you need to replace "\n" by "\\n"?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex to do this and capture all cases at once.

```
str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(\\)+n" withString:@"" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, str.length)];
```